# Try/catch error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I'm a little stuck as to why I'm getting a Try block error when I'm not using one.

I'm receiving the notification of the error near the bottom of the code block. Can someone explain to me why this is happening, if I'm not using a try/catch?

Is it telling me that this is what I should be using instead of the while loop?

Using eclipse juno to develop this web app .

EDIT: Wrapped in a try Statement. But,now I'm getting this error listed below. Removed old error comment for updated code

If anyone needs more code let me know.

Listed Error here so we can see the whole text. Above the catch block

ERROR: *Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     ClassBody
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     Block
    - Syntax error on token "}", delete this 
     token*

```
<tr><td><select name="selBaseCurr">
<%
    while ( ! rs.next()) {
        try{
            if (fEmptyRecordset){
                break;
            }
            if (! fFirstPass){
                rs.next(); //originally rs.getString;
            } else {
                fFirstPass = false;
            }
            if (rs.getString) {
                break;
            }
            if ( ! rs.getString("BASE_CURR_CODE").equals("")){
%>
        <option value="<%=rs.getString("BLMBG_CURR_CODE")%>" <%if (rs.getString("BLMBG_CURR_CODE").trim()) eq (request.getParameter("selBaseCurr").trim());%>selected="true"<%}%>><%=rs.getString("BLMBG_CURR_NAME")%>&nbsp;(<%=rs.getString("BLMBG_CURR_CODE")%>)</option>

<% //Multiple annotations found at this line

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }finally{
            if(fFirstPass = true){
        }
            if (! fEmptyRecordset){
            rs.next();//originally rs.getString;
            }
        }
%>

         </select>
```

Comment: That's the problem. Almost all JDBC operations throw some kind of Exception; you should wrap your code in a try/catch

Comment: both [ResultSet.next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) and [ResultSet.getString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)) throw [SQLException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html), you should have try catch in your code. Moreover why are you writing Java code inside a JSP page???

Comment: I'm writing the code in the JSP page for now, I haven't really set up the classes in a java file. I'm converting ASP code to JSP so i'm kind of following that workflow that someone else did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one extra braces, causing the exception..

```
<tr><td><select name="selBaseCurr">
<%
while ( ! rs.next()) {
    if (fEmptyRecordset){
        break;
    }
    if (! fFirstPass){
        rs.next(); //originally rs.getString;
    } else {
        fFirstPass = false;
    }
    if (rs.getString) {
        break;
    }
    if ( ! rs.getString("BASE_CURR_CODE").equals("")){
   %>
        <option value="<%=rs.getString("BLMBG_CURR_CODE")%>" 
                <%if (rs.getString("BLMBG_CURR_CODE").trim()) eq        
                    (request.getParameter("selBaseCurr").trim());%>
                    selected="true"
                <%}%>>
        <%=rs.getString("BLMBG_CURR_NAME")%>&nbsp;
        (<%=rs.getString("BLMBG_CURR_CODE")%>)</option>
<%
    }

//    }        This one is extra in your code!!

fFirstPass = true;
if (! fEmptyRecordset)
{
    rs.next();//originally rs.getString;
}
%>

     </select>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, I removed that bracket and added a try statement, so far the first error is gone

Answer (score 0):

`Resultset.next()` can throw a SQLException; any call to this method must be wrapped in a try/catch block.